# Help with running first spring 3.0 mvc application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I get below error

I understand few jars are missing from runtime environment but I have all the requeired jars in WEB-INF/lib directory.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1672)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1517)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:208)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>defaulthandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>defaulthandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

```
 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

I am using eclipse. Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 5):

You do not have all the required JARs, you're missing Apache Commons Logging.

http://commons.apache.org/logging/

Comment: antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
jstl.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.5.11.jar
lucene-core-3.0.0.jar
ojdbc14.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar
slf4j-simple-1.5.11.jar
standard.jar , and how does apache commongs logging stop container from loading servlet?

Comment: also I have all spring 3.0.5 jars

Comment: I have all jars in WEB-INF/lib directory, Does eclipse add all these jars to runtime path?

Comment: @Khaleel: As I said, you're missing `commons-logging.jar`. Spring won't work without it.